# Ubuntu 18.04 mariadb access error

Tags: linux, mysql, mariadb

I'm on ubuntu 18.04, i have installed maria-db,

maria-db is running with the command:

```
sudo service mysql status
```

but when i write this command:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

ERROR: i get this error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

i solved this problem by editing my `my.conf` in my MySQL folder: 
i added `skip-grant-tables` in the `[mysqld]` section.

Then when I tried to write a command, like creating a table in my Maria-db  DB using:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

ERROR: it received this error:

```
ERROR 1290 (HY000): The Maria-db server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement
```

Your suggestions could really help me, i have been stuck here for a few days,

i tried to reinstall maria-db, to reconfigure maria-db too, but i get the same error; I tried LOT of solutions but I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: You don't need to run it with `sudo`. There should be a temporary password in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `mysql_secure_install` script in order to init a new DB. Than you can create the user and grant them the access manually.